xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies stopped working after Mac Os update
My config is as follow
MacBook Pro with M3 Pro and Sonoma 14.5 OS
XCode 15.2 Build version 15C500b
swift-driver version: 1.87.3 Apple Swift version 5.9.2 (swiftlang-5.9.2.2.56 clang-1500.1.0.2.5) Target: arm64-apple-macosx14.0 Darwin lonwx2049951 23.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.5.0: Wed May 1 20:13:18 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.121.3~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T6030 arm64
I am behind corp proxy and have quite limited privileges to install or use any tools/commands requiring admin privileges.
The App itself plus a few company submodules are hosted on Azure Devops and this side works as usual.
The App also uses a few dependencies hosted on GitHub and that need to be resolve every time I'm switching/creating new branches
Until Monday I was using following terminal command to do so
xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -scmProvider system
However, on Monday when I tried the above I was presented with error on each of the dependencies
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
The only change that happen was the Mac OS update on Monday morning when I turn on my Mac from 14.4 to 14.5
Is it possible that this update removed some of the settings?
I have tried the following:

deleting DerivedData folder,
cleaning and rebuilding project
cloning the dependencies manually
adding PAT token
using SSH for git operations
deleting Package.resolved file
cloning project from Azure repo into different location

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
